# Class with array where keys are strings and takes integers, doubles and strings

Tags: c#

I'm doing a C# online selfstudy course and there is an assignment I cant figure out.
I am given a half ready application and I need to create a class and all of the members to get it to work. I can not change anything under "class Application". This is the template I'm given:

```
using System;

namespace ObjectOriented
{
// Your Code Here

class Application
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TypeCollection collection = new TypeCollection(3);
        collection["integer"] = 123;
        collection["double"] = 456.78;
        collection["string"] = "Hello world!";

        double sum = (double)(int)collection["integer"] + (double)collection["double"];
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of all numbers is {0}", sum);

        Console.WriteLine();

        TypeCollection collection2 = new TypeCollection(2);
        collection2["integer"] = 123;
        collection2["double"] = 456.78;
        collection2["string"] = "Hello world!";
    }
}
}
```

This is what it is supposed to print:

```
 Added integer = 123
 Added double = 456.78
 Added string = Hello world!
 The sum of all numbers is 579.78

 Added integer = 123
 Added double = 456.78
 Collection is full
```

My biggest problem is how to create array with a key as a string. This is what I tried, but I couldnt get it to accept strings as keys.

```
public class TypeCollection
{
    private object[] colType;

    public TypeCollection(object length)
    {
        this.tyyppi = new object[(int) length];
    }
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return colType[key];
        }
        set
        {
            colType[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `object[]`

Comment: Your collection-object is no array, its - as the name already suigests - a collection. This said you can also access all the collections entries using a key as if it were an array but with also strings as keys and not only indexes.

Comment: make there generic collections one for string one for doubles and one for ints.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for an assignment, I will try to offer some hints as opposed to giving the entire answer.  In this case the [] operator can be used on more than just arrays in C#.  The class is also called TypeCollection, so you should have a look through some of the collections documentation in C# to find a collection to suite your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx

Comment: I agree with this approach - you often find out a lot of interesting stuff whilst digging for something else - it's a shame it was ruined by another users comment!

Comment: This approach fits me fine. Found the Dictionary before reading the comment on my question. But the course I'm taking hasnt mentioned anything about collections. All the theory has been about classes and arrays. So I'm wondering, is there any way to do this, without using Dictionary?

Comment: There are some other collections that can be used, but if you mean in terms of whether or not this is possible to accomplish with arrays in C#, then the answer is "no".  Arrays in .NET compile down to System.Array (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).  There are some interesting things that can be done with arrays in .NET, but the index is always an int (for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx).  I hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Hashtable`. It gives what you want. See the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hashtable collection = new Hashtable();

        collection["integer"] = 123;
        collection["double"] = 456.78;
        collection["string"] = "Hello world!";

        double sum = (double)(int)collection["integer"] + (double)collection["double"];
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of all numbers is {0}", sum);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that use only array and classes you have to go with something like this:

```
public class TypeCollection
{
    class KeyValue // define your key / value object to store the data
    {
        public string Key
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    private KeyValue[] colType;

    public TypeCollection(object length) // why use object instead of int???
    {
        this.colType = new KeyValue[(int)length];
    }
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < colType.Length; i++) // find the key inside the array
            {
                if (colType[i].Key == key)
                {
                    return colType[i].Value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            // this should add new elements so you have to resize the array etc.
            for (var i = 0; i < colType.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colType[i].Key == key)
                {
                    colType[i].Value = value;

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at this as starting point.